# Oracle Unicode Support in 10g and 11g Differences

Tags: oracle

I am running into a problem that I have not yet been able to explain. I have code that takes a number, gets the national character code for the number using NCHR, and then performs a RAWTOHEX conversion on it.

It worked in 10g for years. When we upgraded to 11g it started returning different values. I boiled it all down to a few statements, and created a demonstration script:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
  rawVar RAW(2000);
  nVar NVARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
  nVar :=  NCHR(1112);
  SELECT RAWTOHEX(nVar) INTO rawVar FROM DUAL;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('rawVar: ' || rawVar);
END;
/
```

When executed in 10g, the ouptut is "0458". In 11g (from the same computer and using the same Oracle client software) the output is "00040058". The upstream process that relies on the output is expecting "0458".

Interestingly (to me), if I change the definition of nVar to be an VARCHAR2 instead of an NVARCHAR2, I get "0458" as the output on 11g.

Can someone please help to explain why the results are different?  I have searched Oracle's release notes and support system, but have not found any answers.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: could you run this from a SQL environment:   select nchr(1112) nchr, rawtohex(nchr(1112)) rth from dual;

Comment: Both environment sreutrn the same, NCHR is "?" and RTH is "0458"

Comment: So, it seems like the conversion to varchar in the dbms_output is affecting the value - is this similar to how your upstream process receives the value?

Comment: in the upstream process, the raw variable is passed back to a Java app over JDBC. From there the bits are analyzed and converted back into the original values (long process). With the same code, I get two different results in 10g and 11g - that's what I can't figure out.

Answer (score 1):

This is a horrible bug in Oracle 11
Change

```
nVar :=  NCHR(1112);
```

to

```
nVar :=  CHR(1112 using nchar_cs);
```

and things will work again.
These expressions should be identical, according to Oracle docs. In Oracle 10 this is true, but not in 11.

Answer (score 0):

Are the two databases using the same character set ?

Could you run this query in both instances:

```
select value 
  from nls_database_parameters 
 where parameter='NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET';
```

CHR and [NCHR](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions091.htm#i1273067) functions will only give the same result if the databases have the same character set.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Yes, they are both "AL16UTF16".

Answer (score 0):

RAWTOHEX returns a character value, but you are selecting it into a RAW, so there will be some implicit conversion there. Then you are trying to use DBMS_OUTPUT which will need to implicitly convert that RAW variable into a string.

Potentially you can deal with a RAW value (ie bytes) or a Character value (text which may get converted/translated depending on character set / language settings) or a hex representation of the bytes in the the string. Which of those do you have in the database, and which do you want to return to the application ? Then just do that ONE conversion and do it explicitly.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that the method is not very rational. Howver, my question is why the same code returns different values in Oracle 10g vs. Oracle 11g.

Comment: I'd suspect something has changed in the implicit conversion of RAW to a VARCHAR in multi-byte character sets, but don't have databases to hand to test the assumption.